# Объединение множества Excel файлов в один

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Нужно объединить более сотни .xlsx файлов в один.

Файлы .xlxs однородны, 1 строка - шапка, далее данные с одинаковым кол-вом столбцов.

Сейчас так:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import xlsxwriter

in_3 = 'my_path/concat_excel/*.xlsx'
files = glob.glob(in_3)
# print(files)

df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f, header=None) for f in files], ignore_index=True)

df.to_excel('final.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

with pd.ExcelWriter('final.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel()
```

На выходе ошибка:

> File "C:---path---\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 616, in biff2_8_load
>       raise XLRDError("File size is 0 bytes")
>   xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: File size is 0 bytes

Как решить?
Может быть не на Python, или есть варианты проще это сделать?

Comment: Скажите, вам ясен текст ошибки?

Comment: Изначально нет, после ознакомления с вашим решением начинает проясняться.
Вероятно, он не мог обработать пустой файл, коим являлся final.xlsx, находящийся в этой директории

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

path = Path("my_path/concat_excel")
min_excel_file_size = 100

df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) 
                for f in path.glob("*.xlsx") 
                if f.stat().st_size >= min_excel_file_size],
               ignore_index=True)

df.to_excel('/path/to/final.xlsx')
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это то, что нужно